# Magento2 : massdelete is not working

Tags: magento-2.1.7, delete, massaction

I have created a custom module with ui_component grid, below is my grid xml file :

```
...
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">module_record_custom_list.module_record_custom_list.jbs_module_custom_columns.ids</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
    <action name="delete">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="module/custom/massdelete"/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</massaction>
...
```

And Created a controller file `MassDelete.php` :

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Custom;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Package\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\CollectionFactory;
//use Jbs\CustomStore\Helper\Data;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public $request;
    /**
     * Massactions filter.
     *
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $_filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    //protected $_customstorehelper;

    /**
     * @param Context           $context
     * @param Filter            $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory

        Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) 
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_filter = $filter;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        //$this->_customstorehelper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->_filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
        foreach ($collection as $item) 
        {
            $item->delete();
        }
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize)
        );

        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT)->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

But on select Delete from dropdown I'm getting error as below :

```
"Invalid method Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document::delete"
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check my answer. Maybe that'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are wrong here.

```
foreach ($collection as $item) 
{
     $item->delete();
}
```

You need to load `$item` before deleting it.

```
foreach ($collection as $item) 
{
    $item = $this->YOUR_MODEL->load($item->getId());
    $item->delete();
}
```

Replace `$item->getId()` with your Primary Key.

Hope it'll help you.